# I lend my talents to one man every night

Tags: riddle, knowledge

*I am History and Heritage.

I am a Strand's Source.

I am an Extractor of Enrichment.*

**Who am I?**

Hint for line 1:

> I can be everyone's, some people's, or someone's.

Hint for line 2:

> Strand of something

Hint for line 3:

> What I extract is enriching.

Title Hint:

> I don't do weekends ;)

Comment: *One man every night* only one? Trivial? or Metaphorically used?

Comment: Mmm I don't wanna give it away too much so I won't say more than: in what I am referencing, just one man... but the title may require you to be from a certain country but it's not necessary for the other clues.

Comment: @n_palum If the clue is specific to one country, then should this question have the `trivia` tag?

Comment: @MikeQ I added it, again still not familiar with every tag.. but it could be helpful for the title as I mentioned to techidot, but the rest do not require it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think basically and fundamentally you are

> Roots

I am History and Heritage

> Roots describe a person or group's cultural or ethnic origins

I am a Strand's Source

> A root is where a strand of hair is attached to skin

I am an Extractor of Enrichment

> Plant roots absorb nourishing minerals and water

The title: I lend my talents to one man every night

> The Roots are the house band of The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon airing week nights.

Comment: Isn't there even [a historiical novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roots:_The_Saga_of_an_American_Family) with that name?

Comment: Yes a very profound work. On a different note congratulations to humn on the tantalizing current rep 9999 and above that the 1850 given in bounties.

Comment: Yay someone finally got it! Nice job :)

Answer (score 2):

You are

> The silkworm.

I am History and Heritage.

> The Chinese history and monopoly of silk goes back to 5000 years.

I am a Strand's Source.

> The source of the silk strand.

I am an Extractor of Enrichment.

> Silk is a very expensive material.

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting, but nope not it. Your strand answer has been closer than others so far though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are

> Blood

`I am History and Heritage.` & hint 1

> Every person has blood in their body. People's ancestry and heritage is also known as a bloodline, and people of the same family are said to have the same blood.

`I am a Strand's Source.`

> Red blood cells contain DNA strands.

`I am an Extractor of Enrichment.` & hint 2

> Red blood cells carry oxygen from the lungs, to the rest of the body. If not, the person dies.

As for the title, I don't know. If it is specific to one culture, then I am not familiar with the reference.

Comment: Hmm nice but not it. It connects to all of them. For your first line answer, think of alternatives to that approach and it may help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A **Bank**

I am History and Heritage.

> Banks serve as history of transactions and economical flow. They are also heritage. Also, there is a [Heritage Bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritage_Bank) :)

I am the Strand's Source.

> Banks of river.

I am an Extractor of Enrichment.

> Banks are extractor of money.

### Old

Are you

> A **Sea**

I am History and Heritage.

> Oceans around the world have numerous historical things related to them. Also, they serve as a heritage for many creatures.

I am the Strand's Source.

> Strand can mean the shore of a sea and for us, it is a source for a voyage.

I am an Extractor of Enrichment.

> Precious pearls can be extracted from the sea.

Comment: Hmm.. Very interesting thought but no, not it. You seem to be thinking about having these traits, not being them.

Comment: @n_palum Added another answer :)

Comment: Hmm interesting again - but no not what I am going for.. I'll still hold off on more hints for a bit

Answer (score 0):

You are the

> cerebral cortex.

I lend my talents to one man every night

> The cerebral cortex controls dreams during REM sleep

I am History and Heritage.

> The cerebral cortex is in charge of memories.

I am the Strand's Source.

> The cerebral cortex manages consciousness.

I an Extractor of Enrichment

> The cerebral cortex is  involved in associative learning and attention

Comment: Hmm nice thought but not what I am going for.